# Passing parameters to JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I can successfully pass parameters through Jmeter as long as I embed them in the path like so:
[image]

 But when I try to add them using the GUI, it doesn't work: [image]

 I have tried combinations of encode/unecode, as well as adding "?" to the path, but the result is the same - the server replies that the required parameter is missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used Tree View Listeners for both cases? What kind of request is created by JMeter for second case?? Please share that as well (you can check it in tree view listener).

Comment: I haven't used Tree View. Kaushlendra Jha's answer makes sense though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a post request so pass this name value into Body data (click on body data tab) in json format

> {
>       "Taskid": "9000" 
>   }

or

> {
>       "Taskid": 9000
>   }

if the type of 9000 is string then choose 1st option other wise 2nd, better to try with both options to check which one is working

Other approach:

try to change the method to `get` with same parameters as passed in snapshot2 (attached by you) but it might be possible this request does not supports `get` method then in that situation you have to `post` it only by passing in the Path field (as shown by you in snapshot 1) or in body data tab

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.