# Passing query parameters to GET request via 'Parameters' tab

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I can successfully pass parameters when I embed them in the path like below

[image]

[image]

However, it seems that passing query parameters using Parameters tab doesn't pass them right:

[image]
[image]

Should I use 'Parameters' tab only when I do POST method? I know it's a similar question with [Passing parameters to JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715598/passing-parameters-to-jmeter) but I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the param `page` in the first example and `pages` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are the same so feel free to use the most convenient to you, in case of manually amending the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) you will need to take care of `?` and `&` characters, [URL-encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) the values either manually or via [__urlencode() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) and in case of multiple attributes using "Parameters" section is more readable

[image]